# Dúvida sobre como usar o Identity em camadas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Criei um projeto AspNet MVC com Identity pra entender como funciona a parte do Identity. Fiz alterações no código, inclui roles e claims. Migrei esse projeto para um projeto da empresa, porém o projeto é todo feito em camadas (MVC,Negócio,Repository,DAL). O problema agora é que não estou conseguindo passar os dados para camada de negócio - repository - DAL. Quando vou debugar o código no método Login, meu método SignInManager retorna sempre "Null". Alguém pode me ajudar ? Sou novo na área e não consigo solucionar o problema.

```
//
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login ou Senha incorretos.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Há algum motivo importante para ser feita essa separação?

Comment: Estrutura padrão da empresa.

Comment: Bom, essa estrutura padrão não é bem atendida pelo ASP.NET Identity. O correto seria você implementar o projeto sem a separação e depois separar se houver um motivo melhor que este da estrutura padrão. Aplicar um conceito não-MVC em um projeto ASP.NET MVC está sujeito a essas coisas.

Comment: Entendi. Então o que você aconselha é trabalhar com Identity "funcionando separado" do projeto padrão isso?

Comment: Não, esse projeto não deveria ser separado em camadas. Separar em camadas é uma prática antiga de outro tipo de projeto (*three-tier*). MVC não é *three-tier*. Só é recomendada uma separação dessas quando você precisa de uma arquitetura muito peculiar de serviços (por exemplo, Web API2 + MVC, com ressalvas). Fora isso não tem qualquer motivo para separar.

Comment: O motivo para a separação do Identiy da sua camada de apresentação (MVC) é promover desacoplamento de modo que seja fácil, no futuro, substituí-lo por um outro sistema de membership. Considerando o histórico de sistemas de membership que a Microsoft lança você pode considerar que em menos de 3 anos o Identity já poderá estar ultrapassado. Se isso não for um problema implemente-o junto ao projeto MVC - se for um problema, separe-o.

Comment: Entendi. Mas mesmo assim agradeço @Cigano Morrison Mendez e rcompanhoni pela ajuda de vocês.

Comment: @RaphaelGumm A única maneira adequada de separar por camadas é usando inversão de controle (IoC). Confesso que ainda não tenho conhecimento suficiente para te direcionar uma boa resposta, mas posso indicar alguns links: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-ioc-using-unity-in-mvc-5/

Comment: @AlissonSaggiorato já vi este tutorial, consegui pegar uma noção muito boa sobre Identity, porém é todo em MVC.

Comment: Sem problemas @CiganoMorrisonMendez, vou dar uma olhada no tutorial e ver se consigo extrair alguma coisa. Obrigado.